# What is the meaning of "nurture or nature"?

Tags: meaning

In Horror English movie *Halloween II (2009)* movie, Dr Loomis who once taken care of Michael Myers and conducted
a press meet to say this words:

> Dr Loomis: So it is the fate of all of us to direct our first sexual
>   impulses towards our mothers and our first  murderess hatred against
>   our fathers. Now, in Michael's case, I became the surrogate father.
>   The last father in a long  series of fathers. Well, has anybody got
>   any questions at all? Yes, sir. Yes. Please.
>
> Reporter: You never really made it clear whether you believe it was
>   **nurture or nature** that contributed to Michael's condition.
>
> Dr Loomis: I would like to answer it, in part, by quoting the great
>   George Bernard Shaw with a little  Loomis twist at the end. He says:
>   "In the arts of life, man invents nothing. But in the arts of death,
>   he outdoes nature herself and produces, by chemistry and machinery all
>   the slaughter of plague, pestilence, famine" and Michael Myers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nature_versus_nurture

> The long-running nature versus nurture debate is about whether human behaviour is determined by the environment, either prenatal or during a person's life, or by a person's genes.